# Figuring out total bandwith usage on a Zyxel Zywall

Tags: performance-monitoring, network-monitoring, zyxel, zywall

I've got a Zyxel Zywall USG 100, and I'm trying to figure out the total bandwidth usage. That is, I'd like to find out if some user complaints about speed is related to a saturated connection - or something else.

Is there a way to see the total bandwith usage for a Zyxel Zywall USG 100?

There is a list of counters which shows transferred data by IP, but I can't really use that table for anything useful.I have tried to copy the table to do some sort of snapshot comparison between two points in time in another application, but this is VERY cumbersome as the user interface does not allow me to copy anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain this data for example through SNMP, but you need also a proper monitoring tool to show the data and fire alerts if needed.

I'm going to recommend you what I'm using, Pandora FMS. It allows you to use SNMP, show the data in a web interface, fire alerts, generate reports,...

Take a look and test it by yourself, you would be able to monitor much more than your Zyxel device.